# How should I install fence panels on posts that aren't level?

Tags: fence

Needing to install a 24 foot horizontal board privacy "wall", we sunk one 6"corner Superspike and three more 4" Superspikes. The fence will be in two 12' sections. Our problem is that with uneven ground, the spikes are not all level with each other creating a difference of about 3 inches from one end to the other (this is the slope of the ground). How can we remedy this? should we compensate for the slope by driving three spikes consecutively 1, 2 and 3 inches deeper to make them level? We are also on sandy soil in Southern Ontario, and wonder about the overall stability of Superspikes when the ground freezes and windy conditions.

Comment: No idea what a "Superspike" is - apparently some sort of driven fencepost? Depending on shape below ground, frost movement may well be a concern. Does the manufacturer make any claim that it's suitable for permanent use in a freezing climate? Do they back that up in any way?

Comment: You really need to tell us about your fence design. If you're screwing pre-fab panels onto your posts, you'll have to stair-step them. If you're building custom, what's the issue, exactly?

Comment: I don't think spikes get below the frost line in northern climates, so I don't see how they can NOT heave in the winter. If a super spike is like an EZ-Spike, it is not rated for fences above 4'. See the Warning section: https://www.strongtie.com/fences_decksandfences/ezproducts_productgroup_wcc/p/e-z-base.e-z-mender.e-z-spike#ProductDetails

Comment: I'm in a 42" frost depth zone, and most people don't go that deep with fences. Heave is occasionally a problem where drainage is poor or the water table very high, but that's fairly rare. That said, I don't like those metal supports. They don't provide enough stability for my expectations. You'll have a floppy fence, especially if it's six feet high.

Comment: I dont see spikes working for what you are doing but since you already have the super spikes in the ground let the hose soak the ground for 10 mins then grab your posts up high and move them side to side with all your weight for 5-10 mins if base even starts moving at all then you will have a floppy fence.

Answer (score 2):

For a trivial difference like 3" (large sections of my boundary have at least 3' difference over 24'), I just wouldn't worry about it.  3" in 24' is 1:96, <strike>so nobody will notice that the posts aren't quite vertical.</strike> so put the posts in vertically, and then tweak the panels slightly so that they aren't quite square.

If you want to be really precise about it, sinking the fence into the ground is probably the best approach.

For a larger difference, you would need to staircase the fence, probably with shorter sections (to minimize the difference over each section).

Comment: Are you suggesting that the posts be set out of plumb? Egads. That's 3/4" in six feet, which I'd certainly consider noticeable. I'd keep the posts plumb and tweak the panels first.

Comment: @isherwood - yes I was.  Racking the panels is a better idea though.

Answer (score 1):

Fairly common to just let the fence follow the ground.

or, level top, trim the bottom to follow the ground.